# How to manage Intellij IDEA configuration?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, traccar

I've a Java backend application (Traccar). I compile and start the application selecting the following configuration:

[image]

The I click on run to execute the program, and everything works. My question is: how can I do the same from command line? All the settings in this image, how are they translatable to some commands?
If I have to do run the program from command line, how can I select the main class (org.traccar.Main), the module (-cp tracker-server.main) and so on?
Thank you everybody.

Comment: Isn't IntelliJ IDEA dumping the `java` command and its arguments to the Output Window as the very first line of the output before the app starts?

Comment: no, it isn't unfortunately

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the Output Window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should compile the JAR file first and then run it using something like this:

```
java -jar tracker-server.jar conf/traccar.xml
```